# Merging multiple data frames with missing data in R

Tags: r

I have the following data, which is part of my sample, considering my data set a bit large:

```
df1<-read.table (text=" id
Ali,hok
Bab,mko
Katie,Mon
NA
NA
NA
NA
john,Nulla
NA
NA


", header=TRUE)
```

The second data set is as follows:

```
df2<-read.table (text=" id  Class
Katie,Mon   AS1
Ali,hok MNO1
john,Nulla  KAL1
Katie,Mon   Nook
Bab,mko BAR11

", header=TRUE)
```

I want to get :

```
id        Class
Ali,hok    MNO1
Bab,mko   BAR11
Katie,Mon   AS1
NA           NA
NA           NA
NA           NA
NA           NA
john,Nulla KAL1
NA           NA
NA           NA
```

I have used `fuzzyjoin`, but I did not get the intended output

```
library(fuzzyjoin)
outt<-left_join(df2,df1,by=c("id"="id"))
```

Comment: Have you tried a full join?

Comment: Your `left_join` is not from `fuzzyjoin`.  You may need `regex_left_join` or `stringdist_left_join`

Comment: Error in dists[include] <- stringdist::stringdist(v1[include], v2[include],  : 
  NAs are not allowed in subscripted assignments

Comment: The row with `kazi,jo` doesn't have a similar string  in 'df2'

Comment: For Katie,mon record you have different records, why did you match with AS1 versus NOOK? What was the logic there?

Answer (score -1):

Try a simple `merge` from base R

```
df3 <- merge(df1, df2, all.x=T)
df3
#>            id Class
#> 1     Ali,hok  MNO1
#> 2     Bab,mko BAR11
#> 3  john,Nulla  KAL1
#> 4   Katie,Mon   AS1
#> 5   Katie,Mon  Nook
#> 6     kazi,jo  <NA>
#> 7        <NA>  <NA>
#> 8        <NA>  <NA>
#> 9        <NA>  <NA>
#> 10       <NA>  <NA>
#> 11       <NA>  <NA>
```

Comment: It does not reflect the oucome of intrest